# Upper-bound on expectation of gaussian over half-space

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Suppose I have a multivariate gaussian $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2I_{dxd})$  and a real-valued vector $\theta \in \mathbb{R}^d$. How can I upper-bound the following conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}_X\left[X \mid \theta^\top X > 0\right]$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to obtain a closed-form expression for this expectation. TLDR:
$\mathbb{E}\left[X \mid \theta^T X > 0\right] = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \cdot \frac{1}{\|\theta\|} \cdot \theta.$

For any $\theta \in \mathbb{R}^d$, we can define an orthogonal $d\times d$ matrix $Q_\theta$ such that
the first row of $Q_\theta$ equals $\frac{1}{\|\theta\|} \theta^T$ and others form the orthonormal basis of the [orthogonal complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_complement) of $\{\lambda \cdot \theta, \lambda \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

Since $Q_{\theta}^T Q_{\theta} = I_{d\times d}$, we have
$$\mathbb{E}\left[X \mid \theta^T X > 0\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[Q_{\theta}^T Q_{\theta} X \mid \theta^T X > 0\right] = Q_{\theta}^T \cdot \mathbb{E}\left[Q_{\theta} X \mid \theta^T X > 0\right],
$$ where the last equality is due to linearity of expectation.
Denoting $Y = Q_{\theta} X$, we can write $\mathbb{E}\left[Q_{\theta} X \mid \theta^T X > 0\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[Y \mid Y_1 > 0\right]$. As the standard gaussian random vector has spherically symmetric distribution (which means $Q X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2I_{dxd})$ for any orthogonal matrix $Q$), we also have $Q_\theta X = Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2I_{dxd})$. So,
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[Y \mid Y_1 > 0\right] = \begin{pmatrix}
\mathbb{E}\left[Y_1 \mid Y_1 > 0\right] \\ \mathbb{E}\left[Y_2 \mid Y_1 > 0\right] \\ \vdots \\ \mathbb{E}\left[Y_d \mid Y_1 > 0\right]
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
\mathbb{E}\left[Y_1 \mid Y_1 > 0\right] \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Corresponding conditional CDF of $Y_1 \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ is
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(Y_1 \leq y \mid Y_1 > 0\right) = \frac{\mathbb{P}\left(0 < Y_1 \leq y\right)}{\mathbb{P}\left(Y_1 > 0\right)} = \frac{\mathbb{P}\left(Y_1 \leq y\right) - \mathbb{P}\left(Y_1 \leq 0\right)}{\mathbb{P}\left(Y_1 > 0\right)}.
$$
As $\mathbb{P}\left(Y_1 > 0\right) = \frac{1}{2}$, we obtain the conditional PDF: $f(y) = 2 \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}$ for $y>0$ and $0$ otherwise. This leads to
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[Y_1 \mid Y_1 > 0\right] = \int_0^{\infty} 2 y \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}} \mathrm{d} y = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \cdot \int_0^{\infty} y e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}} \mathrm{d} y = \\ =
\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \cdot \int_0^{\infty} e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}} \mathrm{d}\left(\frac{y^2}{2}\right) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}.
$$

Finally,
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[X \mid \theta^T X > 0\right] = Q_\theta^T \cdot 
\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}, 0, ..., 0\right)^T = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \cdot \frac{1}{\|\theta\|} \cdot \theta.
$$